# How to get mantissa and exponent value separately

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap, exponent

I have seen similar questions but still haven't found the answer to my problem. What I need to do is, I have a String array:

```
private String[] scientificNumberData = "2e3, 2e4, 6e3".split(", "); //[2e3, 2e4, 6e3]
```

I need to separate mantissa and exponent in order to return `List<ScientificNumber>`. As for that, I tried to create Map where the key represents mantissa and List of values exponent, as I might have duplicate keys and cannot separate them in another way.

From this code, my map looks like this: `{2=[3, 4, 3], 6=[3, 4, 3]}`, but should be `2=[3, 4], 6=[3]}`.

Is there any better solution to this or maybe I can fix my code somehow in order to get the right output to use for `List<ScientificNumber>`?

```
public List<ScientificNumber> getScientificNumbers() {

        List<ScientificNumber> result = new LinkedList<>();
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> separateExponent = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        List<Integer> exs = new LinkedList<>();

        int mantissa = 0;
        int exponent = 0;

        for(String str: scientificNumberData){
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
                if(str.charAt(i) != 'e'){
                    if(matiss == 0){
                        if(!(separateExponent.containsKey(str.charAt(i)))){
                            mantissa = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));
                            separateExponent.put(mantissa, exs);
                        }else{
                            mantissa = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));
                        }
                    }else{
                        exponent = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));
                    }
                }
            }
            // if there is a duplicate key already
            if(separateExponent.containsKey(mantissa)){
                separateExponent.get(mantissa).add(exponent);
            }else {
                // if not duplicate key
                separateExponent.put(mantissa, Collections.singletonList(exponent));
            }
             // change back to default values
            mantissa = 0;
            exponent = 0;
        }
        // works, but since wrong output the total will be wrong
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : separateExponent.entrySet()){
            for(int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size(); i++){
                result.add(new ScientificNumber(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(i)));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

ScientificNumber.java file looks like this:

```
public class ScientificNumber {
    private int mantissa;
    private int exponent;

    public ScientificNumber(int mantissa, int exponent) {
        this.mantissa = mantissa;
        this.exponent = exponent;
    }

    public int intValue() {
        return mantissa * Double.valueOf(Math.pow(10, exponent)).intValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you splitting each item between commas by "e", parse the first part as the mantissa and the second as the exponent? That directly gives you a `ScientificNumber`.

Comment: How should `1.2345e9` be stored? As `ScientificNumber(12345, 9)` or `ScientificNumber(12345, 5)`? Or something else? Or will there never be a decimal point in the numbers in the string?

Comment: @Andreas, haven't really thought about it, since all the given values have been integers only

Comment: @daniu can you give me a code example, I'm kinda lost at the moment :)

Comment: Why `Double.valueOf(Math.pow(10, exponent)).intValue()` instead of simply casting with `(int) Math.pow(10, exponent)`? Creating a `Double` object just for converting to `int` is a waste.

Comment: @Andreas casting isn't appropriate for our teacher, so instead of casting, we have to use Double.valueOf :D . I know, It would be much easier

Comment: The `Double.intValue()` method is implemented as `return (int)value;`, so the result is a cast anyway. Creating a `Double` object just to avoid *writing* a cast is idiotic!

Comment: @Andreas I understand, but unfortunately it isn't up to me to decide

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method to the `ScientificNumber` class:

```java
public static ScientificNumber parse(String str) {
    int idx = str.indexOf('e');
    if (idx == -1)
        return new ScientificNumber(Integer.parseInt(str), 0);
    return new ScientificNumber(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, idx)),
                                Integer.parseInt(str.substring(idx + 1)));
}
```

The inverse is of course:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.mantissa + "e" + this.exponent;
}
```

Comment: you mean to ScientificNumber.java ? I cannot change ScientificNumber.java, since I'm not allowed to. :/

Comment: @TheFoxterGirl Ok, then don't. The logic of the method is the same, no matter where you put the code.